# Android listactivity with actionbaractivity

Tags: android

I need combine this, because I can't extend 2 classes. I have tried this solution but I cant do onListItemClick()

[ActionBarActivity of "android-support-v7-appcompat" and ListActivity in Same activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403647/actionbaractivity-of-android-support-v7-appcompat-and-listactivity-in-same-act)

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to use an `ActionBarActivity` with a `ListFragment` inside.

Comment: Yes this is the better approach and it's easily modified to have tabs which contain listfragments.