# Update listview - single row - chat from sqlite

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-sqlite

How I can update a row in my listview (a chat) ?

is easy to make a Customadapter = new (..), but if I have 50000 message? Very slow to make a = new "Always"

How do I update an "x" row?

I try with `adapterMessages.notifyDataSetChanged();` , but not update, is normal, I don't know row from my listview

Example :

```
user1 : hi
                 user2 : hi? (update here) row "x"
user1: is hello
                 user2: aa ok (update here) row "x"
```

I use adapter to update listview, (message receiv or not receiv)
http://fielinks.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/images/double-check-whatsapp.jpg?itok=qBI0LGQL

Comment: i don't understand your question at all,  what adapter are you using?

Comment: I use adapter to update listview, (message receiv or not receiv)http://fielinks.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/images/double-check-whatsapp.jpg?itok=qBI0LGQL

Answer (score 0):

```
listview = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
          listData= getCallDetails();


         listview.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),listData));

 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new  OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int positionToRemove,
                        long arg3) {
    updateFromDb(Id);
    listData.remove(positionToRemove);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: I don't have acces in listData.remove,"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403647/actionbaractivity-of-android-support-v7-appcompat-and-listactivity-in-same-act" but I can put in my customAdapter .remove, but how get id ? I can compare instead of position "text" ?

Comment: setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(..)  I tried, and my debugger of eclipse show, load all message, you think, 15.000 messages + update always, listivew = to slow, and not is a click, is from sqlite..., I need find position of my listview and modify, but findPostionText need, exampple : Hello 12:00h = hello 12:00h == true modify new text ..

Comment: then try to use   listData.get(positionToRemove);later  modify it

Comment: anyway I am getting confused,I am not sure what u wanna

Comment: listData.get(messagText == position = true ) = true how I can do this?

Comment: I don't know position, sqlite update, and I need put(textModify) once, for not find message1 == messagex of 150000 messages

Comment: How I can getPosition of my listview for modify ? from sqlite