# Creating the 'up' action bar within a ListActivity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

My problem is that I cannot seem to get the action bar above the List view as seen in this picture.

[image]

When I use the `extends ActionBarActivity` I lose access to ListView class so cannot use the methods such as `getListView()`.

I attempted to use this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403647/actionbaractivity-of-android-support-v7-appcompat-and-listactivity-in-same-act) and create my own implementation of ListView which I had some success.

The problem here was that I could not get the `onListItemClick` to fire when Items where clicked.

I'm not sure if I missed a step and now need to call it manually, in which case It could just be I do not know/understand the correct parameters for the method, `onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id)`.

So my question in two parts is.

- Is there a way to add the 'up' button to `ListActivity`
- How do I called the `onListItemClick` method if I create the class myself.

Thank you.

EditContactsActivity.java

```
package uk.co.jackdh.tapchat;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseRelation;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

import java.util.List;


public class EditContactsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static final String TAG = EditContactsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;
    protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;
    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;

    private ListView mListView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_contacts);

        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }

    protected ListView getListView() {
        if (mListView == null) {
            mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        }
        return mListView;
    }

    protected void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    protected ListAdapter getListAdapter() {
        ListAdapter adapter = getListView().getAdapter();
        if (adapter instanceof HeaderViewListAdapter) {
            return ((HeaderViewListAdapter)adapter).getWrappedAdapter();
        } else {
            return adapter;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        mFriendsRelation = mCurrentUser.getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_FRIENDS_RELATION);

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.orderByAscending(ParseConstants.KEY_USERNAME);
        query.setLimit(1000);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> parseUsers, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    //success
                    mUsers = parseUsers;
                    String[] usernames = new String[mUsers.size()];
                    int i = 0;
                    for (ParseUser user : mUsers) {
                        usernames[i] = user.getUsername();
                        i++;

                    }
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EditContactsActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, usernames);
                    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);

                    addFriendCheckMarks();
                } else {
                    //error
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EditContactsActivity.this);
                    builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                            .setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void addFriendCheckMarks() {
     mFriendsRelation.getQuery().findInBackground( new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
         @Override
         public void done(List<ParseUser> parseUsers, ParseException e) {
             if (e == null) {
                 //List returned look for match.
                 for (int i = 0; i < mUsers.size(); i++) {
                     ParseUser user = mUsers.get(i);

                    for (ParseUser contact : parseUsers) {
                        if (contact.getObjectId().equals(user.getObjectId())) {
                            getListView().setItemChecked(i, true);
                        }
                    }
                 }
             } else {
                 Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
             }
         }
     });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        getListView().getOnItemClickListener().onItemClick(lv, v, position, id);

        if (getListView().isItemChecked(position)) {
            //add friend
            mFriendsRelation.add(mUsers.get(position));
        } else  {
            //remove friend
            mFriendsRelation.remove(mUsers.get(position));
        }
        mCurrentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null ) {
//                        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

activity_edit_contacts.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="uk.co.jackdh.tapchat.EditContactsActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to add the 'up' button to ListActivity

The answer is [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) in Android developer tutorial. Basically you can continue to use `ActionbarActivity` class and use `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` method to enable it. Then you would handle the `onOptionsItemSelected` method as required for the id `R.id.home`.

> How do I called the onListItemClick method if I create the class myself.

First you have to make your EditContactsActivity class implement the OnItemClickListener interface.

```
 public class EditContactsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener.
```

Then you have implement the onItemClick method. Finally set your class as click listener for the mListView.

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

The detailed tutorial is [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-itemclicklistener-for-a-listview-with-images-and-text/)

Comment: Thanks, Looking at that second answer and the tutorial. I don't actually need to use `implements OnItemClickListener` as I can call `.setOnItemClickListener` without it.