# How to make ContextualMenu in ListView with subItems?

Tags: java, android

I try make a `contextualMenu` about a list with subItems (index(group)). My class first `extends actionBarActivity`, and declares my list.

My adapter `extends of BaseExpandableListAdapter` (SubItems). I need acontextual menu, so in my main class, I have a method :

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    getListAdapter();
}
```

This `getListAdapter` method basically has code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403647/actionbaractivity-of-android-support-v7-appcompat-and-listactivity-in-same-act).

But I when touch, it does not work. How I can fix this problem?

Comment: register the context menu like registerForContextMenu(yourlistview); then try

Comment: My list is ExpandableListView, but works correctly

Comment: I've edited your question to make it a bit more readable. Make sure you check the editor's help, as well as the preview. The easier your question is to read, the easier it would be for us to help you. Also: consider repeating enough of the code from the other question to make it a full repro. This makes it easier for others to help out.